# Convert number to floating point on key press or key up or key down

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web site in which i want the number to be formatted in the given requirement that is as below:

- If I press "1" it should say "1".
- If I press "12" it should say "12".
- If I press "123" it should say "1.23".
- If I press "1234" it should say "12.34".
- This sequence should also work when I press backspace.

I have developed it on my own that is as below:

```
        function Maskme(obj, evt) {

        var event = (window.event) ? window.event : evt;

        var str = document.getElementById("txtamt");
        if (event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 13) {

            if (str.value.length == 3 && str.value.indexOf(".") == -1) {
                var val = parseFloat(str.value);
                var val1 = (val / 100).toFixed(2);
                str.value = val1;
            }
            else if (str.value.length > 3) {
                var val = parseFloat(str.value) * 1000;
                var val1 = (val / 100).toFixed(2);
                str.value = val1;
            }
            else {
                str.value = str.value;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (event.keyCode != 13) {
                var str1 = parseFloat(str.value) / 10;
                if (str1 != 0 && !isNaN(str1))
                    str.value = (str1).toFixed(2);
                else
                    str.value = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am having problem that is:

1. If I rapidly press "123" it says "12.30" or "12.3" instead of "1.23"
2. Backspace is also not working after I reach back to 1.23
3. maximum 7 digits are allowed to enter in the text field

If there any ready made plugin available or anyone has already developed this kind of plugin then please inform me I will appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to replace the dot first and then the calculate is pretty easy:

```
$("#txtamt").keyup(function(obj, evt) {
    var event = (window.event) ? window.event : evt;

    //ignore arrow keys so that user can move curser 
    switch(event.keyCode)
    {
        case 37:
        case 38:
        case 39:
        case 40:
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }                

    var str = document.getElementById("txtamt");
    str.value = str.value.replace(".", "");

    if (str.value.length == 3) {
        var val = parseFloat(str.value);
        var val1 = (val / 10).toFixed(1);
        str.value = val1;
    }
    else if (str.value.length > 3) {
        var val = parseFloat(str.value);
        var val1 = (val / 100).toFixed(2);
        str.value = val1;
    }        
});
```

​

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ceJcn/7/
​

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, changed

Comment: Above solution works fine after I modified it a little bit but I also forgot to post 3rd problem that is maximum 7 digits are allowed to enter in the text field so can you please able to do that..?

Comment: I also don't know how to embed that example in my source code..can you help me regarding that..?

Comment: Ok..Now I have ambeded it in my website and it works fine..but as this is the application works in tablet so it has one issue that is when user press 1234 then "12.34 is going in as 12.43"

Comment: About the 7 digits you can change it to use double instead of float to get a bigger range, not sure why tablet works like that way, it sounds like the cursor position changed during user entering values, can you reproduce the issue consistently?

Comment: That may be the issue, so can you resolve that..? and yes for maximum 7 digit..you understood it wrong..I mean this "12345.67" after this if I press anything, should not allowed to enter..

Comment: I've updated the demo link, and I just use the maxlength on the input to limit the length to 8 so that only 7 digits is allow(1 more for dot), sorry I don't have a tablet so can't see what's the real problem is, I added a switch to bypass arrow keys so that user can move cursor next to some digits, but there are still lots of room to   improve this code, like only allow digit numbers etc.

Comment: Yes...Now the Maximum limit works but the original conversion is stoped working...

Comment: hmm... maybe it's about those keycode checks, it work for me, sorry about I don't have any tablet...

Comment: Ya...It only works in Crome but not in Firefox..You can check that..
Let's forget about all this, I will handle that.
Thanks for all your great effort..
Thank You very much "Simon Wang"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ZH3Td/)

It could possibly be more elegant, but it seems to do what it is supposed to do

```
var x = document.getElementById("x");
x.focus();
x.select();
var tId;
x.onfocus=function() {
    var fld = this;
    tId = setInterval(function() {
        var val = fld.value;
        if (val.length>2) {
          if (val.indexOf(".") ==-1) {
            if (val.length==3) val = parseFloat(val/10).toFixed(1);
            else val = parseFloat(val/100).toFixed(2);
          }
          else if (val.length==4) val = parseFloat(val).toFixed(1);
          else if (val.length<=3) val = parseInt(val);
          else val = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
          fld.value=val;
        }
    },10);
}
x.onblur=function() { clearInterval(tId)}
```

Comment: If I enter 1234 yes I get 12.34, but then as you force only 4 digit and I keep press 6 lots of times the number will be change

Comment: That is how I understood the spec. Only 4 digits allowed. and I do not use keyup/keypress so I cannot return false

Comment: I mean I keep key in 6 it will change to 12.35, 12.36, 12.37, 12.38.Interesting side effect

Comment: I know ;) I'll attempt to fix it if necessary